# How to test a service class that has @Autowire on a repository with spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been sitting with this all day, and I just dont get why this is not working. Furthermore this test does work with a spring boot project, but for some reason in this spring framework project this test does not work and the error thrown is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean found for dependency
>   [com.globati.repository.DealRepository]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/spring/DealServiceTest-context.xml"})
public class DealServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    DealService dealService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Test
    public void createDeal() throws ServiceException {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
//        Employee employee = new Employee("Daniel", "tuttle", "danielptm@me.com", "dannyboy", "secret password", 23.234, 23.23);
//        Deal d = dealService.createDeal("ADSF/ADSF/cat.jpg", "A title goes here", "A deal description", 23.22, "Name of business", 23.23,23.23, employee, "USA" );
//        Assert.assertNotNull(d);

    }
```

DealService looks like this:

```
@Service
public class DealService {

    @Autowired
    private DealRepository dealRepository;

    DealService(){}

    public DealService(DealRepository dealRepository){
        this.dealRepository = dealRepository;
    }


    public Deal createDeal(String image, String title, String description, double distance, String location, double targetLat, double targetLong, Employee employee, String country) throws ServiceException {
        Deal deal = new Deal(image, title, description, distance, location, targetLat, targetLong, employee, country);
        try {
            return dealRepository.save(deal);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not create a deal: "+deal.toString(), e);
        }
    }

    public Deal updateDeal(Deal d) throws ServiceException {
        try{
            return dealRepository.save(d);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not update deal at this time: "+d.toString(),e);
        }
    }

    public List<Deal> getAllDealsForEmployeeId(Employee employee) throws ServiceException {
        try{
            return dealRepository.getAllDealsBy_employeeId(employee.getId());
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException("Could not get deals for employee: "+employee.getId(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

DealRepository looks like this

```
public interface DealRepository extends CrudRepository<Deal, Long>{

    public List<Deal> getDealsBy_country(String country);

    public List<Deal> getAllDealsBy_employeeId(Long id);

}
```

I have a config file that looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.globati.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class InfrastructureConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseProject");
        config.setUsername("awesome");
        config.setPassword("database");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

//  @Bean
//  public DataSource derbyDataSource(){
//      HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
//      config.setDriverClassName("jdbc:derby:memory:dataSource");
//      config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true");
//      config.setUsername("awesome");
//      config.setPassword("database");
//
//      return new HikariDataSource(config);
//
//  }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); //Get data source config here!
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.globati.model");

        return factory;
    }
```

This is how the directory structure of my project looks
[image: Directory structure of project]

DealServiceTest-context.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

            <!-- this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class -->
    <bean id="dealService" class="com.globati.service.DealService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.globati.service.EmployeeService">
        <!-- set properties, etc. -->
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id="employeeRepository" class="com.globati.repository.EmployeeRepository">-->

    <!--</bean>-->

            <!-- other beans -->
</beans>
```

For some reason this @Autowire over DealRepository in DealService is behaving differently than in the spring boot project where this works. Any ideas as to how I can solve this error and do a unit test on the service class would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a test `profile` for `DataSource` as follows,

```
@Bean
@Profile("test")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseProject");
    config.setUsername("awesome");
    config.setPassword("database");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

Then annotate your test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` as follows,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/spring/DealServiceTest-context.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DealServiceTest {
```

This will make sure that you get a `DataSource` when you are executing within the test case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I still get the same error.

Comment: can you share your entire dir structure? where is your DealServiceTest-context.xml?

Comment: Yes ill put it up in just a moment

Comment: I added an image of the directory structure as well as how the DealServiceTest-context.xml file looks.

Comment: in your DealServiceTest-context.xml can you please add DataSource definition please

Comment: Yes, I will do that, just trying to figure out how.

Comment: Im having the same problem now that I was having yesterday, I am not finding good examples of how to write this context file used by the tests. If you have an example or could refer me to a place that has a good example, then I could more easily include the DataSource definition suggestion that you made.

Comment: if it is in resources dir then it is already in classpath. So access it in same manner you did. If those files are in WEB-INF then use file:project_path_dir